# How to debug nokia wrt application start?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, symbian, nokia-wrt

I wrote an application with Phonegap and jQuery mobile. The app is small, little messy at the moment, but it works in Android without problems. I ported the sources to wrt, replaced phonegap.js with symbian verison, added info.plist, icon and so on.

Application can be installed without problem, but it dies on startup. It shows a white page for a second and then exits.

Does anyone have an idea how to debug startup of wrt application?

My test device is Nokia C6.00 with Symbian^1 5th edition.

Best regards,
SWilk

Answer (score 0):

Nokia has a tool called "Web App Simulator" for S40 phones: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Web/Tools/Nokia_Web_Tools/
I'm not sure if you application will be able to work in S40 environment, but "Web App Simulator" seems to be supporting debugging.
Otherwize may be a simple debug logging will be useful: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_debug_widgets

Answer (score 0):

The obvious reason for this is the **version of the jQuery** which you included in the app. Nokia for C6-00 i.e. Symbian^1 5th edition support jQuery 1.2.6 (read some where on Nokia Dev site). if you remove the link to this file, your app will open up.

Comment: link to the Nokia page is - http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/GuaranaUI-Overview

See section jQuery.